# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, xmlhttprequest, undefined

I am learning how to use HTTPClientModule in Angular 4.3
I have imported correctly in app.module.ts and I am trying to make an http Request GET. This is my app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
interface Card {
  card: [{
    cardClass: string,
    cost: number;
  }];
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {


    this.http.get<Card>('https://api.hearthstonejson.com/v1/21517/enUS/cards.collectible.json').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data.card); //This is not working returning undefined
      console.log(data); //This is not working (removing <Card>)
    });

  }

}
```

Why data.card is undefined? How ca I have access to the element of the object here to pass then into an array of Cards?
Thanks for any help

Comment: can you post your HTML template with the question ?

Comment: In my angular project I use Http instead of HttpClient, maybe it helps you?

Comment: Http is (or will be) deprecated, HttpClient is the way to go now...

Comment: @rinukkusu is right if this is not your domain, you need to take additional measures to allow communication with it. Check the 2nd arg of the `subscribe` (it is an error arg).  Also look at `devtools` to see what happened.  If not CORS, it's likely some sort of error accessing the remote site.

Comment: CORS is not a problem, just tried that.

Comment: Yep, tried it, too - that's why I deleted my comment :)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, btw I had tried also with hhtp with previous version of angular and was working using .map also. but I wanted to try to use the HTTPClientModule instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API returns array of objects, but your `Card` interface is defining object with `card` property. You need to use interface that will describe the response, like this:

```
interface Card {
  cardClass: string;
  cost: number;
}

interface CardArray {
  [index: number]: Card;
}

this.http.get<CardArray>('https://api.hearthstonejson.com/v1/21517/enUS/cards.collectible.json').subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data[0]); // first card
  console.log(data); // all cards
});
```

Or even simpler approach:

```
this.http.get<Card[]>('https://api.hearthstonejson.com/v1/21517/enUS/cards.collectible.json').subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data[0]); // first card
  console.log(data); // all cards
});
```

Comment: Thanks!!! This solved the problem indeed. I realised the card interface had some issues but I couldn't' figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

try to add `map` method along with `json` method just before subscribe:

```
this.http.get<Card>('https://api.hearthstonejson.com/v1/21517/enUS/cards.collectible.json')
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data.card); //This is not working returning undefined
    console.log(data); //This is not working (removing <Card>)
  });
```

Comment: There is no `json` method on response from HttpClient. It will automatically parse the JSON response for you (unless you tell it not to do so).

Comment: sorry, my mistake, confused with old HttpModule

Comment: for convenience I created a plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/JZiYveU76SfeNp31MRfL?p=preview which shows just first card as suggested @MartinAdámek